# Symfony Doctrine Readonly Entity with data managed using migrations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am looking for advice on what the best practices for scenario below might be.

## Scenario

I have some entities that use what I call "data as part of the schema": their data is part of the software and are not to be created/edited/deleted by the software during normal operation.

I'm using these to provide fixed lists of choices for other entities without using enum fields - because those are really part of the column definition and if I need to alter the column in any other way than to append a new value it results in a full table copy.

Such an entity is defined like this - readOnly=true parameter, manually assigned ID, unique slug, unique user-visible name, and private constructor. This isn't a good candidate for fixtures because it's not test data (talking about how Doctrine Fixtures wants to delete my "data as schema" is for another SO question)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(readOnly=true)
 */
class SubmissionStatus
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, unique=true)
     */
    protected $slug;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, unique=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    private __construct() {}

    // ... other fields
}
```

I manage the values using Doctrine Migrations:

```
final class Version20181023132831 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        $statuses = [
            ["id" => 1, "name" => "Pending", "slug" => "pending"],
            ["id" => 2, "name" => "Reported", "slug" => "reported"],
            ["id" => 3, "name" => "Rejected", "slug" => "rejected"],
            ["id" => 4, "name" => "Accepted", "slug" => "accepted"],
        ];

        foreach ($statuses as $status) {
            $this->addSql("INSERT INTO submission_status (id, name, slug) VALUES (:id, :name, :slug WHERE id = :id", [
                "id" => $status['id'],
                "name" => $status['name'],
                "slug" => $status['slug'],
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

I do `UPDATE` and `DELETE` in future migrations if I need to update these values - also massaging existing Foreign Keys referring to these rows if necessary.

Other entities have `@ORM\ManyToOne` relationships to this entity.

## The problem

What is the best way to refer to these in code?

Not all of these entities will be selected by users in `ChoiceType` fields in forms or come in through API calls. Some of them will be used just in code like `$otherEntity->setStatus(...)`

## Current solution

Currently we've settled on doing this:

We're storing constants in the entity class for the IDs and slugs.

```
class SubmissionStatus
{
    const PENDING_ID = 1;
    const PENDING_SLUG = 'pending';
    const REPORTED_ID = 2;
    const REPORTED_SLUG = 'reported';
    const REJECTED_ID = 3;
    const REJECTED_SLUG = 'rejected';
    const ACCEPTED_ID = 4;
    const ACCEPTED_SLUG = 'accepted';
}
```

When we need to `setStatus`, we make database lookups:

```
$status = $em->getRepository(SubmissionStatus::class)->findOneBy(['slug' => SubmissionStatus::ACCEPTED_SLUG])
$otherEntity->setStatus($status);
```

## Question

Is there are better way to do this?

I'm not a big fan of writing all that `getRepository->findOneBy` boilerplate all the time, especially if I need to reference several of this kind of entities. I would like something short, easy and quick to write when doing it repeatedly.

I would also prefer not to have to change too many places when I make changes to the values. One in the migration and one in the class constants is quite enough.

## What I've thought of so far

I can't add a helper function to the entity itself (e.g. `setStatusAccepted()` or `setStatus(SubmissionStatus::ACCEPTED_SLUG)`) because I can't look up the referred entity from there.

An injected service which does a lookup on creation and stores references. Its usage would be e.g. `$entity->setStatus($statusRef->accepted)`, `$entity->setStatus($statusRef->get(SubmissionStatus::ACCEPTED_SLUG))`. The first option breaks IDE code completion. The second one is a bit too long, even though shorter than `$em->getRepository->find`

Answer (score 0):

There is a property annotation that will help keep your IDE happy.

```
/**
 * One entry for each status 
 * @property-read SubmissionStatus $accepted 
 */
class SubmissionStatusReference
{
    public function __get($slug) {
        switch($slug) {
            // blah blah blah
            case 'accepted': 
                return $this->entityManager->getReference(etc...
```

I think this is the cleanest way to actually answer your question.

But having said that, I eventually stopped doing this sort of thing and instead of making actual status entities I just use slugs.  Initially I was concerned about being able to change values and what not but as a practical matter I hardly ever need to do so.  I use view transformers to convert the slugs to what you call names.  And no id at all.